# JPQL for finding if user has sent or recieved friend request from an other user

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have been developing simple social networking project, I was to implement `User -> Friend` relationship as AppUser.java:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "users")
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class AppUser extends AuditModel {

    @NonNull
    private String userName;

    @NonNull
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String userEmail;

    private String userPassword;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy="owner", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Friend> friends = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

and Friend.java

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "friends")
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"owner"}) // to avoid StackOverflow
@ToString(exclude = {"owner"}) // // to avoid StackOverflow
public class Friend{

    @NonNull
    @EmbeddedId
    private Key key = new Key();

    @NonNull
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("ownerId")
    private AppUser owner;

    @NonNull
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("personId")
    private AppUser person;

    @NonNull
    private boolean accepted;

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Embeddable
    public static class Key implements Serializable {
        private Long ownerId;
        private Long personId;
    }
}
```

If user sends friend request to an other user records be like:

[image: friends_table view]

At this point every thing is working fine except the case where I want to hide `Add Friend` button on profile page of the User who has sent me a friend request or I have sent him a friend request, I tried with the `JPQL` in FriendRepository.java as:

```
@Repository
public interface FriendRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Friend, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT count(f) FROM friends f WHERE (f.owner.id = :id OR f.person.id = :id)")
    Integer findPendingOrFriend(@Param("id") Long id);

}
```

and in Service I have:

```
    public boolean findPendingOrFriend(Long id) {
        // Find friends ids who/Whom friend requests are sent
        return friendRepository.findPendingOrFriend(id) > 0;
    }
```

in controller I have:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{userId}/profile")
public String showProfile(
        Model model,
        @PathVariable(value = "userId") Long userId
) throws Exception {

    // Send model
    String pageTitle = "User " + Util.getLoggedInUser(userService).getUserFirstName() ;
    model.addAttribute("pageTitle", pageTitle);
    model.addAttribute("loggedInUser", Util.getLoggedInUser(userService));
    model.addAttribute("profileUser", userService.findById(userId).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new));

    // Check if pending or friend
    boolean isPendingOrFriend = friendService.findPendingOrFriend(userId);
    model.addAttribute("isPendingOrFriend", isPendingOrFriend);
    return "user_profile";
}
```

but it does not work as expected, because it hides `Add Friend` button for a new user who have not sent any friend requests to any other user of the Application and when a friend request is sent it always shows `Add Friend` button on user profile page. 
Question is how can I re-write

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT count(f) FROM friends f WHERE (f.owner.id = :id OR f.person.id = :id)")
    Integer findPendingOrFriend(@Param("id") Long id);
```

so that it will work as desired above.

Comment: what will change when you send a request, which attribute will be changed?

Comment: @sc0der please see the update.

Comment: I have post one, hope this works!

Answer (score 1):

Your query will not work, because you check that owner id or person id which not correct,

you should check both ids for the visitor id and owner's page id

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT count(f) FROM friends f WHERE ((f.owner.id = :id1 AND f.person.id = :id2) OR (f.owner.id = :id2 AND f.person.id = :id1))")
    Integer findPendingOrFriend(@Param("id1") Long id1, @Param("id2") Long id2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind the scenario I would rather go with the following:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT count(f) FROM friends f WHERE (f.owner.id = :oId AND f.person.id = :pId) OR (f.person.id = :oId AND f.owner.id = :pId)")
Integer findPendingOrFriend(@Param("oId") Long oId, @Param("pId") Long pId);
```

And in `Service`:

```
public boolean findPendingOrFriend(Long oId, Long pId) {
     // Find friends ids
     return friendRepository.findPendingOrFriend(oId, pId) > 0;
}
```

and in Controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{userId}/profile")
    public String showProfile(
            Model model,
            @PathVariable(value = "userId") Long userId
    ) throws Exception {

        AppUser loggedInUser = Util.getLoggedInUser(userService);

        // Send model
        String pageTitle = "User " + loggedInUser.getUserFirstName() ;
        model.addAttribute("pageTitle", pageTitle);
        model.addAttribute("loggedInUser", loggedInUser);
        model.addAttribute("profileUser", userService.findById(userId).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new));

        // Check if pending or friend
        boolean isPendingOrFriend = friendService.findPendingOrFriend(loggedInUser.getId(), userId);
        model.addAttribute("isPendingOrFriend", isPendingOrFriend);
        return "user_profile";
    }
```

hope this works as desired.